# modify variables outside of function scope from within a function in python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.5

How can I obtain the following result? I want to mutate `L`(list of integers) to contain only values, if value is greater than `x`(any integer). Any changes are to be done only within the function `applyAdd(L, x)`.

```
def applyAdd(L, x):
        L =[i for i in L if i>x]
        return max(L)
```

when the following input is give in IPython console:

```
L = [0, -10, 5, 6, -4]
print(applyAdd(L, 3))
print(L)
```

I get the following output

```
6
[0, -10, 5, 6, -4]
```

Instead I want

```
6
[5, 6]
```

I know `L` doesn't have scope outside of the function.
My question is, is there anyway to modify `L` from within `applyAdd(L, x)` function.

I got this as assignment, any help is much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Assignment as in homework? Why would any school/college/university teach "bad" coding practices (writing code that has side effects can be dangerous in practice as it may introduce hard to find bugs). It's also not very pythonic IMO (If you really need to have side effects both the function and the variable should be encapsulated in a class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not working, because the generator will new a new list inside function.

```
def applyAdd(L, x):
        L =[i for i in L if i>x]
        print(id(L)) #some different value

L = [0, -10, 5, 6, -4]
print(id(L)) #some value
```

**Solution1. Use global variable instead**

```
L = [0, -10, 5, 6, -4]

def applyAdd(x):
    global L
    L =[i for i in L if i>x]
    return max(L)

print(applyAdd(3))
print(L)
```

**Solution2. Keep using generator**

```
def applyAdd(L, x):
    X = ([i for i in L if i>x])
    L.clear()
    L.extend(X)
    return max(L)

L = [0, -10, 5, 6, -4]
print(applyAdd(L, 3))
print(L)
```